# MATLAB Startup Error: no write permission

Tags: matlab

I installed MATLAB in ubuntu 14.04. When starting it, an error occurred as shown. It says there is no write permission.

[image: matlab startup error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if the `~/.matlab` directory is owned by root. Make yourself owner of the directory:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.matlab
```

This is useful if you have tried to launch MATLAB with `sudo` or straight from the install.

Reference: [Matlab not starting properly on Unix/Linux](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98599-why-will-matlab-not-start-up-properly-on-my-linux-or-unix-based-system)